# Workflow in Symfony doesn't work with "multiple_state"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony-workflows

In one of the configuration files of Symfony 5.2.8 with Workflow 5.2.7 I have:

```yaml
    framework:
        workflows: 
            register_participation:
                type: 'workflow' # or 'state_machine'
                audit_trail:
                    enabled: true
                marking_store:
                    type: 'multiple_state'
                    arguments: 
                        - complexState
               # [...]
```

When I execute **bin/console** I have error:

> Unrecognized option "arguments" under framework.workflows.workflows.register_participation.marking_store". Available options are "property", "service", "type".

When I change the configuration to:

```yaml
    framework:
        workflows: 
            register_participation:
                type: 'workflow' # or 'state_machine'
                audit_trail:
                    enabled: true
                marking_store:
                    type: 'multiple_state'
                    property: state
       #         [...]
```

I get the error:

> The value "multiple_state" is not allowed for path framework.workflows.workflows.register_participation.marking_store.type". Permissible values: "method"

It **works** when I change to this:

```
        marking_store:
            type: 'method'
            property: main_state
```

Anybody have idea what can I do to works with multiple_state? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [symfony workflow documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/workflow.html):

> The marking store type could be “multiple_state” or “single_state”. A
> single state marking store does not support a model being on multiple
> places at the same time. This means a “workflow” must use a
> “multiple_state” marking store and a “state_machine” must use a
> “single_state” marking store. Symfony configures the marking store
> according to the “type” by default, so it’s preferable to not
> configure it.
>
> A single state marking store uses a string to store the data. A
> multiple state marking store uses an array to store the data.

So if you configure type "workflow" it should automatically be "multiple_state". You could dump your entity and the state property should be of type array